# Chrome Extention V3. Service Workers doesn't have mediaDevices

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, service-worker

Can't find mediaDevices within Service Worker.

[navigator doesn't contain 'mediaDevices'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiUrO.png)

Here is part of Manifest :

```
  "permissions": [
    "desktopCapture",
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "notifications",
    "background",
    "cookies",
    "activeTab",
    "scripting"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [{
    "resources": ["app.html"],
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
  }]
```

Ther is any ways how to 'add' mediaDevices into navigator?

Comment: I need this due to getUserMedia(); I'm trying to run capturing Webcam, Audio and Screen (tab, window) streams.

Comment: There's no way. You'll have to open a separate page or keep using ManifestV2. BTW you can do it in an iframe added to the page, there's no need for service worker.

Comment: @Alexey did you find any solution to this?